# gnuplot stacked histogram, first column is the key, second column the stack index

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to obtain from data like this

```
a 2023-10 1
a 2023-11 2
b 2019-10 2
b 2019-12 3
b 2020-06 4
```

a stacked histogram like this

```
│
│                              ┌─────┐
│                              │2020 │
│                              │06   │
│                              │     │
│                              │     │
│                              │     │
│                              │     │
│                              │     │
│                              ├─────┤
│                              │2019 │
│                              │12   │
│                              │     │
│                              │     │
│            ┌─────┐           │     │
│            │2023 │           │     │
│            │11   │           ├─────┤
│            │     │           │2019 │
│            │     │           │10   │
│            ├─────┤           │     │
│            │2023 │           │     │
│            │10   │           │     │
└────────────┴─────┴───────────┴─────┴───────────────────────────
                a                 b
```

i.e.

- first column is the x-axis
- second column is the n-th element of the histogram for the respective x element (in this example it's a date but it doesn't matter)
- third column is the value of the respective element

Comment: If the linked question does not answer your question or if there are issues, edit your question and post your script and describe your specific problem in detail.